# What are Virtual Walls in House Flipper 2?

Tags: house-flipper-2

In [RTGame's video of House Flipper 2](https://youtu.be/-h7NmahACqg?t=2193), a Virtual Walls option is shown in the build menu. Selecting it displayed purple wireframes along the roof of the house. It was quickly toggled off as they didn't understand what the feature did.

What does the Virtual Walls option do in House Flipper 2?

[image: Menu with Virtual Walls]

[image: Purple wireframes after selecting Virtual Walls]

Comment: Seeing the image gave me an idea that this feature is showing hitbox of the walls, but not sure since I don't have this game.